# Plotly Violin Plot Add Trace cannot add names

Tags: python, plotly, violin-plot

the example code from the website:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.colors import n_colors
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

# 12 sets of normal distributed random data, with increasing mean and standard deviation
data = (np.linspace(1, 2, 12)[:, np.newaxis] *random.randn(12, 200) + 
    (np.arange(12) + 2 * np.random.random(12))[:, np.newaxis])

colors = n_colors('rgb(5, 200, 200)', 'rgb(200, 10, 10)', 12, colortype='rgb')

fig = go.Figure()
for data_line, color in zip(data, colors):
    fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=data_line, line_color=color))

fig.update_traces(orientation='h', side='positive', width=3, points=False)
fig.update_layout(xaxis_showgrid=False, xaxis_zeroline=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

If I add name = 'Sample' to:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=data_line, line_color=color, name = 'Sample'))
```

the chart changes dramatically and is meaningless.  How Do I add a name to the traces so they no longer read 'trace 0', 'trace 1' etc. ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `name` argument of `go.Violin`. **But the names should be different**. Here is the modified example (I set it to the number of the trace just as an example):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.colors import n_colors
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

# 12 sets of normal distributed random data, with increasing mean and standard deviation
data = (np.linspace(1, 2, 12)[:, np.newaxis] *np.random.randn(12, 200) + 
    (np.arange(12) + 2 * np.random.random(12))[:, np.newaxis])

colors = n_colors('rgb(5, 200, 200)', 'rgb(200, 10, 10)', 12, colortype='rgb')

fig = go.Figure()
for i, e in enumerate(zip(data, colors)):
    data_line, color = e
    fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=data_line, line_color=color, name=i))

fig.update_traces(orientation='h', side='positive', width=3, points=False)
fig.update_layout(xaxis_showgrid=False, xaxis_zeroline=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this is great.  however when I extend it to fit my needs, all the graphs flatten out.  I have a list called Dates: Dates = ['2001-06','2005-06','2009-06', '2014-06', '2019-06'] and I make the small change name=Dates[i] in my code the graphs change

Comment: my graph doesn't have as many lines - ie why the Dates list is shorter

Comment: if I substitute name=Dates[i], and Dates = ['2001-06','2005-06','2009-06', '2010-06','2011-06','2012-06',
         '2013-06','2014-06','2015-06','2016-06','2017-06','2019-06'] , graphs turn flat

Comment: It seems Plotly parses the dates for the y axis and therefore we have flat lines. If you add something to the date string, for instance a dot at the end (``name=f"{Dates[i]}."``), you have the desired behavior. I don't know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't let plotly convert the datetime implicitly. Use `strftime()` to get your desired format and use that value to update the "name" or "y0" attribute to get the desired results. This will resolve the issue, however I think it's a bug in Plotly. I have raised an issue. Until then use this hack :)

Follow the below example

```py
fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x = violin_plot_data.loc[:,metric_name] , 
                                    orientation = 'h',
                                    width = 3 ,
                                    side = 'positive',
                                    name = date.strftime('%b %d'),
                                    meanline_visible=True,
                                    points = False,
                                   )
                         )
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtJtw.png):

[image]

Comment: Consider adding a link to the issue you raised.